# Software to browse the Web as moving character

Tags: web-browser, web

In *Mega Man Battle Network*, the characters move around the Web as a 3D environment.

Or imagine having a 2D sidescrolling character moving through webpages.

Or imagine walking through a gallery of paintings except the paintings are websites and you can jump into them like Mario.

Is there something that lets you browse the Web in any such way?